# Java Lambda - check if an ArrayList to Stream is empty

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have the following lambda expression and if works fine when `bonusScheduleDurationContainers` is not empty. If it is empty, I get a `NoSuchElementException`.  How do I check this in the lambda expression?

```
final List<ScheduleDurationContainer> bonusScheduleDurationContainers
        = scheduleDurationContainersOfWeek.stream()
                                          .filter(s -> s.getContainerType() == ScheduleIntervalContainerTypeEnum.BONUS)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

final ScheduleDurationContainer bonusScheduleDurationContainer
        = bonusScheduleDurationContainers.stream()
                                         .filter(s -> s.getDayOfWeekStartingWithZero() == dayOfWeekTmp)
                                         .findFirst()
                                         .get();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`Stream.findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), its up to you to check if the optional has a value rather than just calling get.

You could use the [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) method to return a default value if the optional is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add what is the type of bonusScheduleDurationContainers. Also it is due to the findFirst().get Function. See the documentation. It states that there will be a [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--). You should use [orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-)